# javascript side menu uncluttering

Tags: jquery, html, css, navbar

I've been fixing a website of one of my friends and I need some help.
he has a side bar that has some submenus that are ordered like this:

```
<ul id="nav">
<div id="nav-scroll">
  <li id="hasnav1"><a href="#">item 1</a>
    <ul id="nav1">
        <li><a href="#">item 1-1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item 1-2</a></li>
    </ul></li>
  <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
  <li id="hasnav2"><a href="#">item 3</a>
    <ul id="nav2">
        <li><a href="#">item 3-1</a></li>
    </ul</li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

in total there are currently 3 different hasnav id-tags and the javascript in the index is the following:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#hasnav1").hover(function(){
$("#nav1").stop();
$("#nav1").show();
$("#nav1").animate({opacity:1, left:250},500);
},
function(){
$("#nav1").stop();
$("#nav1").animate({left:"0px", opacity:0},400) }); });

</script><script>

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#hasnav2").hover(function(){
$("#nav2").stop();
$("#nav2").show();
$("#nav2").animate({opacity:1, left:250},500);
},
function(){
$("#nav2").stop();
$("#nav2").animate({left:"0px", opacity:0},400)}); });

</script><script>

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#hasnav3").hover(function(){
$("#nav3").stop();
$("#nav3").show();
$("#nav3").animate({opacity:1, left:250},500);
},
function(){
$("#nav3").stop();
$("#nav3").animate({left:"0px", opacity:0},400)}); }); </script>
```

I have to find a way to merge this code into one simple script instead of in 3 different because I have to add 4 more submenus in there...

thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove the script tags between them and make that one script tag. Ta-Da.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum That wouldn't solve anything, I need to get rid of the 3 different hasnav% and nav% id-tags so I can simply add new submenus without having to add practically the same javascript each time

Comment: Use a common class for all your navigations and maybe something like `data-offset` for the left value (if it changes) so you can reduce that code.

Comment: @elclanrs That is the idea, but if I simply rename them all to hasnav and subnav, they will all appear at the same time.

Comment: You can then target them by `index` and increment the delay where necessary.

Comment: @elclanrs won't that require different target for each submenu? I was thinking of maybe some way to have it target it as child of each <li> tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First. Use class names... This is what they're for.

```
<ul id="nav-main">
  <li class="hasnav"><a href="#">item 1</a>
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#">item 1-1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item 1-2</a></li>
    </ul></li>
  <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
  <li class="hasnav"><a href="#">item 3</a>
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#">item 3-1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

With this in place, you can simplify your code:

```
$(function(){
    $(".hasnav").hover(function(){
        $(".nav",this).stop().show().animate({opacity:1, left:250},500);
    },function(){
        $(".nav",this).stop().animate({left:"0px", opacity:0},400)
    }); 
});
```

For future readers, `$(".nav",this)` is saying **"Find an element with class 'nav' that is a child of the element that is currently being hovered"**. This is referred to as specifying the "context" of the selector.

Comment: Thanks, that was what I had in mind, but for some reason I didn't think of using class names...

Answer (score 1):

**If you can't change the HTML**, try this, just **one** `script` tag and a bit of method chaining, with a `^` (starts with selector) to condense it into one method:

**If you can change the HTML, use a class then change the `hasnav` selector**

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $("id[^=hasnav]").hover(function(){
            $(this).children("ul").stop().show().animate({opacity:1, left:250},500);
        },
        function(){
            $(this).children("ul").stop().animate({left:"0px", opacity:0},400);
        });
    });
</script>
```